union and group biometrics logs in mysql database
I have this table from fingerprint sensor and I need to show the result in one row
ID |  DateTime                | Flag

41 |  2017-02-22 08:05:56.000 | I
41 |  2017-02-22 18:11:03.000 | O
41 |  2017-02-23 23:45:56.000 | I
41 |  2017-02-24 08:11:03.000 | O
Result needed like this:
ID |  IN-DateTime             |  OUT-DateTime

41 |  2017-02-22 08:05:56.000 | 2017-02-22 18:11:03.000
41 |  2017-02-23 23:45:56.000 | 2017-02-24 08:11:03.000

Take next event datetime for rows with flag 'I'.
Then filter rows with flag 'I'.
Considered IN without OUT.
See example



D
DateTime
Flag




41
2017-02-22 08:05:56
I


41
2017-02-22 18:11:03
O


41
2017-02-23 23:45:56
I


41
2017-02-24 08:11:03
O


42
2017-02-24 08:12:03
I


42
2017-02-24 08:12:05
I


42
2017-02-24 08:12:08
O



select *
from(
  select *
    ,case when flag='I' then
      case when lead(flag)over(partition by d order by datetime)='O'
          then lead(datetime)over(partition by d order by datetime)
      end
     else datetime
    end outtime
  from test
)t
where flag='I'




D
DateTime
Flag
outtime




41
2017-02-22 08:05:56
I
2017-02-22 18:11:03


41
2017-02-23 23:45:56
I
2017-02-24 08:11:03


42
2017-02-24 08:12:03
I
null


42
2017-02-24 08:12:05
I
2017-02-24 08:12:08



fiddle
More wired case:
IN without OUT and OUT without IN



D
DateTime
Flag




41
2017-02-22 08:05:56
I


41
2017-02-22 18:11:03
O


41
2017-02-23 23:45:56
I


41
2017-02-24 08:11:03
O


42
2017-02-24 08:12:03
I


42
2017-02-24 08:12:05
I


42
2017-02-24 08:12:08
O


43
2017-02-24 08:12:08
I


43
2017-02-24 08:12:18
O


43
2017-02-24 08:12:28
O


43
2017-02-24 08:12:38
I


43
2017-02-24 08:12:48
O



select d
  ,case when flag='I' then datetime
   end IN_datetime
  ,case when flag='O' then datetime 
   else outtime
   end OUT_datetime
from(
  select *
    ,case when flag='I' then
      case when lead(flag)over(partition by d order by datetime)='O'
          then lead(datetime)over(partition by d order by datetime)
      end
     else 
        case when lag(flag)over(partition by d order by datetime)='I'
          then lag(datetime)over(partition by d order by datetime)
      end
    end outtime
  from test
)t
where flag='I'
 or(flag='O' and outtime is null)




d
IN_datetime
OUT_datetime




41
2017-02-22 08:05:56
2017-02-22 18:11:03


41
2017-02-23 23:45:56
2017-02-24 08:11:03


42
2017-02-24 08:12:03
null


42
2017-02-24 08:12:05
2017-02-24 08:12:08


43
2017-02-24 08:12:08
2017-02-24 08:12:18


43
null
2017-02-24 08:12:28


43
2017-02-24 08:12:38
2017-02-24 08:12:48



fiddle
Update1. For MySQL 5.7, where window functions (LAG,LEAD ...) not available, possible take next (previous) value by subquery.
See simplest query, when all IN and OUT events have pair.
select d,DateTime IN_datetime
   ,(select min(datetime) from test t2 
     where t2.d=t.d and t2.datetime>t.datetime) OUT_datetime
from test t
where t.flag='I';

Or
select t.d,t.datetime IN_datetime, nexttime OUT_datetime
from(
  select *
   ,(select min(datetime) from test t2 
     where t2.d=t.d and t2.datetime>t.datetime) nexttime
  from test t
)t
left join test t3 on t3.d=t.d
  and t3.datetime=t.nexttime
where t.flag='I'
order by t.d,t.datetime
;

We can also consider cases, where sequences 'I' after 'I' - next In without OUT, or 'O' after 'O' - next OUT without IN
select t1.d,t1.flag
  ,case when t1.flag='I' then t1.datetime 
   end IN_datetime
  ,case when t1.flag='I' and t3.flag='O' then t1.nexttime 
        when t1.flag='I' and t3.flag='I' then null 
        when t1.flag='O' and t3.flag='O' then t1.datetime
   else cast('2000-01-01' as datetime)
   end OUT_datetime
  ,t3.flag -- , nexttime
from (
  select *
   ,(select min(datetime) from test t2 
     where t2.d=t.d and t2.datetime>t.datetime
   ) nexttime
  from test t
)t1
left join test t3  on t3.d=t1.d
  and t3.datetime=t1.nexttime
where (t1.flag='I' and t3.flag='O')
  or(t3.flag='I' and t1.flag='I')
  or(t3.flag='O' and t1.flag='O')
order by t1.d,t1.datetime;




d
flag
IN_datetime
OUT_datetime
flag




41
I
2017-02-22 08:05:56
2017-02-22 18:11:03
O


41
I
2017-02-23 23:45:56
2017-02-24 08:11:03
O


42
I
2017-02-24 08:12:03
null
I


42
I
2017-02-24 08:12:05
2017-02-24 08:12:08
O


43
I
2017-02-24 08:12:08
2017-02-24 08:12:18
O


43
O
null
2017-02-24 08:12:18
O


43
I
2017-02-24 08:12:38
2017-02-24 08:12:48
O



fiddle
expressions like
(t1.flag='I' and t3.flag='O')
  or(t3.flag='I' and t1.flag='I')
  or(t3.flag='O' and t1.flag='O')

can be shortened. I left them as they are for clarity.

The OP appears to be running MySQL 5.7.

Thank you. I didn't notice this condition.

But let me give you an uptick for the good effort +1.

Assuming that in and out records would always be paired, we can try the following approach using ROW_NUMBER():
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Flag ORDER BY DateTime) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'I' THEN DateTime END) AS "IN-DateTime",
    MAX(CASE WHEN Flag = 'O' THEN DateTime END) AS "OUT-DateTime"
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID, rn
ORDER BY ID;

Note: The above will only work on MySQL 8+, which has the ROW_NUMBER() window function available.

Can you suggest another option aside from using 'ROW_NUMBER()'

I actually don't know of any alternative, sorry.

It's Okay, Thank you for the help.
